# $\mathbb P(X<Y)=\mathbb P(X>Y)$ for i.i.d. rvs: formal conceptual proof

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. random variables. Intuitively it's obvious (in fact I'd never thought about proving it until some minutes ago) that
$$\mathbb P(X<Y)=\mathbb P(X>Y)$$
And this can be proved formally by computing the probability via Fubini's theorem (independence is invoked to construct a product measure, as usual):
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X>Y)&=\int\mathbf 1_{X>Y}~d\mathbb P\\
&=\iint\mathbf 1_{x>y}~dF(x)dF(y)\\
&=\int (1-F(y))dF(y)\\
&=\int (1-F(x))dF(x)\\
&=\mathbb P(Y>X)
\end{align}
But the proof is not satisfying for me since it involves too many tools and is based on non-direct computation. I have the feeling that a nice proof of this "simple" fact should be almost conceptual and computation-free. But unfortunately such a proof found no way into my mind. Is there a way that is more elegant, i.e., conceptual, to attack the problem? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. one has
$$
P_{(X,Y)}=P_X\otimes P_Y=P_{(Y,X)}.
$$
In particular, if $A=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid u<v\}$, then 
$$
P(X<Y)=P_{(X,Y)}(A)=P_{(Y,X)}(A)=P(Y<X).
$$

Comment: Nice proof! The symmetry is presented in a neat way. Thanks a lot!